# Could not get unknown property 'GROUP' for object of type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library

I want to use blackfizz/EazeGraph in my project and for that I downloaded it and imported it as a module to my empty "hello world" Android project. I am using android studio v3.5.3 using sdk manager v26 and this is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdsafi.testchartline"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

But when I import that I'm getting this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\HP\Documents\Testchartline\EazeGraphLibrary\gradle_mvn_push.gradle' line: 48

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':EazeGraphLibrary'.
> Could not get unknown property 'GROUP' for object of type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 1s
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'GROUP' for object of type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove

```
apply from: 'maven-push.gradle'
```

from your build gradle file for the module you are trying to add.
Next, include

```
implementation project(':module_name')
```

in the dependencies of your main project's build gradle file.

The module you are trying to add was originally in maven. Since the new module is local, you don't need the maven code.

Comment: thanks. I had to import a library by hand. so I encountered this error and your solution helped me.

Comment: Thanks, its working now after i remove apply from: 'maven-push.gradle' .